# Can deleting an email in Outlook (Outlook Web Access or OWA) trigger an exploit?

Tags: email

Assume I have a clean system, network, and up-to-date browser.

Let's say someone sends a malicious email to my Outlook inbox. I know not to open it, preview it, or download and run any attachments.

My question is: if I delete the malicious email, could that trigger some type of exploit and compromise my account? I am specifically looking for answers regarding the Outlook website (outlook.com), and not the program.

Comment: Interesting question. There have been cases where groups have been able to create malicious Outlook rules within peoples' accounts, including ones that blocked emails meant to notify the user that their account may have been compromised! [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3037670/new-rules-are-being-created-automatically-in-outlook) is an old article that talks about this in greater detail. Perhaps someone with more experience can provide more insight into this.

Comment: So unless there was some compromise on the Outlook.com level, you leaked your Outlook credentials, or otherwise downloaded malware in some fashion and had some malicious rules set within your account, then I don't believe it is possible for emails to impact you unless they are interacted with.